# Circular buffer filling up faster than AVAudioSourceNode render block can read data from it

Tags: multithreading, audio, core-audio, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I am experimenting with AVAudioSourceNode, having connected it to the mixer node for output to the speaker. I am a bit of a newbie to iOS and audio programming so I apologize if this question is ignorant or unclear, but I will do my best to explain.

In the AVAudioSourceNode render block, I am attempting to retrieve received stream data that has been stored in a circular buffer (e.g. I currently use a basic implementation of a FIFO buffer but am considering moving to a TPCircularBuffer). I check to see if the buffer has enough bytes for me to fill the audiobuffer with, and if so I grab those bytes for output; if not, I either wait, or take what I can and fill the missing bytes with zeros.

In debugging, it appears I am running into a situation where the circular buffer is filling up *a lot* faster than the render block makes the call to access to the buffer to retrieve data from it. And understandably, after running OK for a few instants, once the circular buffer is full (I'm not even certain how large I should realistically make it but I guess that's another question), the output becomes garbage.

It is as if the acts of filling the circular buffer with streaming data (and probably other tasks as well) are taking priority over the calls made within the render block. I thought that audio operations involving the audio nodes would automatically be prioritized but it may be that I haven't done what is needed to make this happen.

I have read these threads:

[iOS - Streaming and receiving audio from a device to another ends in one only sending and the other only receiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031790/ios-streaming-and-receiving-audio-from-a-device-to-another-ends-in-one-only-se)

[Synchronising with Core Audio Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978305/synchronising-with-core-audio-thread/21999628?noredirect=1#21999628)

which appear to raise similar issues in substance, but a little more current guidance and explanation for my level of understanding and situation would be helpful and very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For playing, the audio system will only ask for data at the specified sample rate.  If you fill a circular buffer at faster than that sample rate for an extended period of time, then it will overflow.

So you have to make sure your sample generator or incoming data stream complies with the sample rate for which the audio system is configured, no more and no less (other than strictly bounded bursting or latency jitter).  The circular buffer needs to sized large enough to cover the maximum burst sizes plus maximum latency jitter plus any pre-fill plus a safety margin.

Another possible bug is trying to do to much inside the render block callback.  Thus Apple recommends not using any code that requires memory management or locks or semaphores inside real-time audio callbacks.